# Set multiple var's onchange?

Tags: javascript, forms, select

If you're using a select dropdown and using an onchange script, can you use it to set multiple var's from this? So for example:

```
<form>
  <select name="select" id="options" onchange="updatevariable(this.value)"> 
    <option value="1">Option One - £1.50</option>
    <option value="2">Option Two - £12.50</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3 - £20.00</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

And then use something like:

```
function updatevariable(data) { 
    options = data;

if(options = '1'){ description = 'Option One', price = '1.50';  }
else if(options = '2'){ description = 'Option Two', price = '12.50'; }
else if(options = '3'){ description = 'Option Three', price = '20.00'; }
 }
```

To then use these values after?

Comment: Yes, but since you know that data before you output the HTML, why create an if/elseif jungle? Store the data in an array or in the `<option>` elements themselves.

Comment: if/elseif seemed the most obvious way to me for such a small function. And Gelatin, yes that was the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your if/else statements to `==` which is a comparison, not `=` which sets the value

```
if(options == '1'){ description = 'Option One', price = '1.50';  }
else if(options == '2'){ description = 'Option Two', price = '12.50'; }
else if(options == '3'){ description = 'Option Three', price = '20.00'; }
```

Comment: Well spotted but OP seems to be asking a much broader question.

Comment: What an idiot! I found an example and modified it, assumed Javascript's if situations worked differently to PHP, but it appears not!? Thanks.

Comment: in PHP the if statement is the same as in JS. :) you need to use == instead of =.

Comment: Yep, i'm used to using PHP, but assumed from the example I followed that JS used a single =, assumption was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

here is an array version of your update function:

```
function updatevariable(data) { 
options = data;

ar[1]=['Option One','1.50'];
ar[2]=['Option Two','12.50'];
ar[3]=['Option Three','20.00'];

description = ar[options][0];
price = ar[options][1];

}
```